# Fetching SQLITE python with Kivy

Tags: android, python, sqlite, kivy

super noob here. I finished my first python program and it works exactly like its intended. Its a simple search engine for a small databse. Now im trying to port it as an android APP with Kivy. What i want to do now is simply display the content of my entire sqlite database (20 rows or so) from a function that works well in the original software.

In the android app, the function list_table seems to work cause it does display the 'printed text', but not the element of the database themselves. Basically it only prints " MVA: "  .Im really not sure why. Ive been trying for a while to find a solution but im stuck :/

Thanks for your help folks.

```
#This is my main.py file

from kivy.app import App
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


import time



Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)

class SearchWidget(BoxLayout):
    def list_table(self, *args):
        try:
            con = lite.connect('data.db')
            con.text_factory = str
            cur = con.cursor()

            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mva ORDER BY mva ASC")
            con.commit()
            ar = cur.fetchall()

            for item in ar:
                data = 'MVA ' + str(item[1]) + str(item[2]) + ': ' +      str(item[0])  + ' ' + str(item[3])

            return data

    except lite.Error, e:

        if con:
            con.rollback()

        print "Error %s:" % e.args[0]
        sys.exit(1)

    finally:

        if con:
            con.close()


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return SearchWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
      MyApp().run()
```

And this is my my.kv file

```
<SearchWidget>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        id: my_textinput
        font_size: 25
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 100
        text: 'MVA Search'

    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
            size: self.texture_size
            text: root.list_table()
            font_size: 25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. i dont think root.list_table() is a good idea..i think it should rather be called from a Button
2. i havent tried running this code, it clearly doesnt point to any work on the UI..if u want to add a widget to the boxlayout, you can do this.forgive my indentation.

   ```
   def list_table(self, *args):
       try:
           con = lite.connect('data.db')
           con.text_factory = str
           cur = con.cursor()

       cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mva ORDER BY mva ASC")
       con.commit()
       ar = cur.fetchall()

       for item in ar:
           data = 'MVA ' + str(item[1]) + str(item[2]) + ': ' +      str(item[0])  + ' ' + str(item[3])
           self.add_widget(Label(text=data))

       return data`
   ```